# Community wiki question

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

I have this question I would like to ask on the main site, but I don't think it is ideally fit for a question per-se, it is more like something I'd be curious about. I was thinking of making it a community wiki question, where people could propose their own answers as community wiki answers only, so nothing to generate an overflow of redundant answers triggered by the desire to amass reputations.

However, it doesn't appear like it is an option. Would there be another decent solution to accomodate my request?

Comment: Some reading material: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature used to exist, and [it was removed](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/). The intended use for community wiki questions was precisely what you seem to be suggesting: things like “what's your favorite …?”, or “let's make a list of …”. Answers were forcibly made community wiki, so they were easy to edit and the whole thread didn't confer anybody reputation.

The feature was removed because it didn't work. Even without reputation at stake, you'd pretty much always get one of two things: either the question didn't gather much interest and its answers were too incomplete to be useful; or the question gathered some interest and it had a mess of disorganized, redundant, poorly-explained answers. Voting on answers tended to reflect primarily who posted first, secondarily how superficially attractive the answer was (+100 bonus for posting a cartoon), and not much how useful the answer was.

Depending on what your not-really-a-question is, some options include:

- An ordinary question.
- Chat.
- A wiki outside of Stack Exchange.
- A question with a single wiki answer.
- Technically, moderators can make a question community wiki. But there would have to be a good reason to think that it would be better than the 99% that failed.

Comment: So how would a question with a signle wiki answer work, if I was to think it would be my preferred choice?

Comment: @Montéedelait You post the question and also self-answer it as a community wiki, then ask the mod to put a lock on the question to prevent additional answers.